# Ansible error: Authentication to smtp.office365.com:587 failed, please check your username and/or password

Tags: ansible

I'm running into this error and even though it said that authentication failed, my username and password are definitely correct.

```
            "from": "maryam.mustaffa@xx.com.sg",
            "headers": [],
            "host": "smtp.office365.com",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "port": 587,
            "secure": "try",
            "sender": "maryam.mustaffa@xx.com.sg",
            "subject": "AD Replication Check - 2019-12-16",
            "subtype": "html",
            "timeout": 20,
            "to": [
                "maryam.mustaffa@xx.com"
            ],
            "username": "maryam.mustaffa@xx.com.sg"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Authentication to smtp.office365.com:587 failed, please check your username and/or password",
    "rc": 1
```

I have googled and can't seem to find the solution.
Edit: So sorry I completely forgot to add in my playbook:

```
  mail:
    attach: /tmp/{{ attachment }}
    subject: "{{ subject }}"
    host: smtp.office365.com
    port: 587
    body: "{{ email_body }}"
    username: maryam.mustaffa@ncs.com.sg
    password: _Leodanielandra1
    from: maryam.mustaffa@ncs.com.sg
    to: "{{ recipient }}"
    subtype: html
    secure: starttls
  delegate_to: localhost
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
```

Comment: pls paste the playbook

Comment: @smily hi so sorry I have added it in

Answer (score 0):

like smily said; always provide example code. That said, smtp.office365.com probably doesn't like the encryption settings. The default is "try", overrule that by adding :

```
 secure: starttls
```

Comment: hi, I changed the secure type and it still gave the exact same error :/